# MacBook Pro 2019 suddenly dead and does not turn on

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, startup, motherboard

While I was doing a heavy task using my MacBook pro 2019, it got freeze suddenly (the color wheel keeps spinning). Then after 1 or 2 seconds the MacBook Pro suddenly shut down. Now it is not turning on. There is even no screen indicator or no chime when I plug the charger. Also, I did SMC reset and NVRAM reset. But still no luck. What should be the reason for that and what are the possible solutions?

- No errors in the screen
- No sound

Comment: My 2019 MacBook Pro went black today when I was programming in Visual Studio Code. I haven't been able to turn it back on, and the people at the Apple Store Genius Bar couldn't either. This computer is basically in new condition. It should not have a problem. What ended up being your solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you have power issues, the most likely cause is hardware.

1. Follow precisely the steps to reset your SMC
2. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295

This is something you want to do once, not regularly reset it - more than three resets in a month = a trip to repair for us at work.

Your machine has a T2 chip, so that also controls power on, so in rare cases if you can't boot to external media / Internet Recovery, you might have success reviving or restoring the firmware portion of the T2 system which can make all the data unrecoverable - so also read that through a couple times before attempting any portion in the middle.

1. https://support.apple.com/guide/apple-configurator-2/revive-or-restore-mac-firmware-apdebea5be51/mac

When these steps fail or you decide it’s hardware, seek someone trained to diagnose and repair your mac. Good options are at the consultant and Apple service locations listed at https://locate.apple.com

Comment: Followed precisely the steps to reset SMC. But did not work. If I plug the AC adapter into the mac, there is no indication from the screen or no chime. Is it completely dead?

Comment: Ok @GRTZ then it’s just a hardware repair situation you face. I edited in next steps above...